# Qt Copy and Paste within QTableView not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am designing a user interface with several functions. On the .ui I have a QTableView. After right click on the table view I open a dialog with the same QTableView so in this way is easier to visualize data. 
After Trying to copy and paste some of the values say, from a cell to another or from a column to another column I have a weird behavior that I don't know how to solve. Below I try to copy `ctrl+C` the selected cell:

[image]

And paste it `ctrl+V` I obtain a weird behavior:

[image]

For some reasons I am copiyng the header "longitude" on the second row instead of the number 24. Additionally the number 200 is pushed below.

This code also allows to copy and paste from the QTableView to an Excel file, this functions works well but I decided to include it in the explanation so you know how I handle all the loops.

**editdialog.h**

```
private:
    Ui::editLeftTableDialog *ui;
    QSqlTableModel *mModel;
    QAction *mActionAppendRow;
    QAction *mActionDeleteRow;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
```

**editdialog.cpp**

```
void editLeftTableDialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    {
        QAbstractItemModel * modelRemoveAdd = ui->tableViewLeft->model();
        QItemSelectionModel *selectionModel = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel();
        QModelIndexList selectedRows = selectionModel->selectedRows();

        QAbstractItemModel * modelNew = ui->tableViewLeft->model();
        QItemSelectionModel *selectedIndexes = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel();
        QModelIndexList selectedInd = selectedIndexes->selectedIndexes();

        // Make sure one row is selected
        if(!selectedRows.isEmpty())
        {
            if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Insert)
                mModel->insertRows(selectedRows.at(0).row(),
                                   selectedRows.size());
            else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
                mModel->removeRows(selectedRows.at(0).row(),
                                   selectedRows.size());
        }
        // Make sure one cell selected
        if(!selectedInd.isEmpty())
        {
            if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Delete)
                foreach(QModelIndex index, selectedInd)
                    mModel->setData(index, QString());
            else if(event->matches(QKeySequence::Copy))
            {
                QString text;
                QItemSelectionRange range = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel()->selection().first();
                for(auto i = range.top(); i <= range.bottom(); ++i)
                {
                    QStringList rowContents;
                    for(auto j = range.left(); j <= range.right(); ++j)
                        rowContents << mModel->index(i,j).data().toString();
                        text += rowContents.join("\t");
                        text += "\n";
                }
                QApplication::clipboard()->setText(text);
            }
            else if(event->matches(QKeySequence::Paste))
            {
                QString text = QApplication::clipboard()->text();
                QStringList rowContents = text.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
                QModelIndex initIndex = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().at(0);
                auto initRow = initIndex.row();
                auto initCol = initIndex.column();
                for(auto i = 0; i < rowContents.size(); i++)
                {
                    QStringList columnContents = rowContents.at(i).split("\t");
                    for(auto j = 0; j < columnContents.size(); j++)
                    {
                        mModel->setData(mModel->index(initRow + i, initCol + j), columnContents.at(j));
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    // Copy from QTableView to an Excel or CSV file happens here and works well
    QAbstractItemModel * model = ui->tableViewLeft->model();
    QItemSelectionModel *selection = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel();
    QModelIndexList indices = selection->selectedIndexes();
    if(indices.isEmpty())
        return;
    QMap<int, bool> selectedColumnsMap;
    Q_FOREACH (QModelIndex current, indices)
    {
        selectedColumnsMap[current.column()] = true;
    }
    QList<int> selectedColumns = selectedColumnsMap.uniqueKeys();
    int minCol = selectedColumns.first();
    // prepend headers for selected columns
    QString selectedText;
    Q_FOREACH (int column, selectedColumns)
    {
        selectedText += ui->tableViewLeft->model()->headerData(column, Qt::Horizontal, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        if(column != selectedColumns.last())
            selectedText += QLatin1Char('\t');
    }
    selectedText += QLatin1Char('\n');
    qSort(indices);
    int lastRow = indices.first().row();
    int lastColumn = minCol;
    Q_FOREACH(QModelIndex current, indices)
    {
        if(current.row() != lastRow)
        {
            selectedText += QLatin1Char('\n');
            lastColumn = minCol;
            lastRow = current.row();
        }
        if(current.column() != lastColumn)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < current.column() - lastColumn; ++i)
                selectedText += QLatin1Char('\t');
            lastColumn = current.column();
        }
        selectedText += ui->tableViewLeft->model()->data(current).toString();
    }
    selectedText += QLatin1Char('\n');
    QApplication::clipboard()->setText(selectedText);
}
```

Comment: That's two different questions, it would be fine if you asked them separately.

Comment: Thanks Michael O. I edited the question leaving the first one.

Comment: Column datas (header inclus) will be copied to clipboard (for excel) when an item was selected, that why you have the column header pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A messy code always brings problems, so I'm not going to analyze it but I'm going to propose an appropriate method where we create a function for each task, and instead of using keyPressEvent you can use a QShorcut:

**editlefttabledialog.h**

```
#ifndef EDITLEFTTABLEDIALOG_H
#define EDITLEFTTABLEDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
class QSqlTableModel;

namespace Ui {
class EditLeftTableDialog;
}

class EditLeftTableDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit EditLeftTableDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~EditLeftTableDialog();
private slots:
    void copy();
    void paste();
private:
    Ui::EditLeftTableDialog *ui;
    QSqlTableModel *mModel;
};

#endif // EDITLEFTTABLEDIALOG_H
```

**editlefttabledialog.cpp**

```
#include "editlefttabledialog.h"
#include "ui_editlefttabledialog.h"

#include <QShortcut>
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QClipboard>

EditLeftTableDialog::EditLeftTableDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::EditLeftTableDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mModel = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    mModel->setTable("test_table");
    mModel->select();
    ui->tableViewLeft->setModel(mModel);

    QShortcut *shortcut_copy = new QShortcut(QKeySequence::Copy, ui->tableViewLeft);
    connect(shortcut_copy, &QShortcut::activated, this, &EditLeftTableDialog::copy);

    QShortcut *shortcut_paste = new QShortcut(QKeySequence::Paste, ui->tableViewLeft);
    connect(shortcut_paste, &QShortcut::activated, this, &EditLeftTableDialog::paste);
}

EditLeftTableDialog::~EditLeftTableDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void EditLeftTableDialog::copy()
{
    QString text;
    QItemSelectionRange selection_range =  ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel()->selection().first();
    for(int i=selection_range.top(); i <= selection_range.bottom(); i++){
        QStringList row_content;
        for(int j= selection_range.left(); j <= selection_range.right(); j++){
            row_content << mModel->index(i,j).data().toString();
        }
        text += row_content.join(QChar('\t')) + QChar('\n');
    }
    QApplication::clipboard()->setText(text);
}

void EditLeftTableDialog::paste()
{
    QModelIndex start = ui->tableViewLeft->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().first();
    QString text = QApplication::clipboard()->text();
    int i=0, j=0;
    for(const QString & row_string:  text.split("\n", QString::SkipEmptyParts)){
        j=0;
        for(const QString & col:  row_string.split("\t", QString::SkipEmptyParts)){
            QModelIndex ix = mModel->index(start.row() + i , start.column()+ j);
            if(ix.isValid()){
                ui->tableViewLeft->model()->setData(ix, col);
                mModel->submit();
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```